# Does Google offer any data about search queries languages per country?

Tags: google, google-search, local-seo, statistics

For example I need to see what percent of searches originated from Iraq is in English vs Arabic vs Kurdish.

Comment: Google doesn't publish such data and if they did it wouldn't be free.

Comment: I don't think they will even do that for money, otherwise most of PPC marketing guys will moved to that, and will spam till the end of all query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't release global search statistics and metrics such as languages used to search and they are considered proprietary and are used internally by Google to improve services. You can access this information for your site specifically by using Google Analytics to see the languages uses by your end users when they access your site.